# enabling a new service in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-17.04

I used the suggested answer from this post to make a custom service in my ubuntu 17.04 environment: [Installing gitblit GO as service in Ubuntu Server 16.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/866825/installing-gitblit-go-as-service-in-ubuntu-server-16-04)

Unfortunately when I hit

> sudo systemctl enable gitblit_server.service

I receive

> Failed to enable unit: File gitblit_server.service: Invalid argument

as an error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

---

Update:

result for journalctl -xe

```
Sep 01 16:06:22 git-dmz01 sudo[7121]: msoadmin : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/etc/systemd/system ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl enable gitblit_server.service
Sep 01 16:06:22 git-dmz01 sudo[7121]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by msoadmin(uid=0)
Sep 01 16:06:22 git-dmz01 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gitblit_server.service:12] Missing '='.
Sep 01 16:06:22 git-dmz01 sudo[7121]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

content of my file gitblit_server.service:

```
[Unit]
   Description=gitblit Server CVS
   After=network.target
[Service]
   User=msoadmin
   Type=simple
   WorkingDirectory=/opt/gitblit
   PIDFile=/var/run/gitblit.service.pid
   ExecStartPre=/opt/gitblit/java-proxy-config.sh
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -server -Xmx1024M -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar
   /opt/gitblit/gitblit.jar --baseFolder /opt/gitblit/data --dailyLogFile

[Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You are using the wrong answer to create custom services. To start with, custom service files should not be placed within `/lib/systemd/system`, rather you'd use `/etc/systemd/system/your_custom_file.service`. Secondly, after creating the service file you'd run `systemct daemon-reload` to notify systemd about your newly created file. Make sure you've restored `SELinux` file context and so on.

Comment: I moved it to /etc/systemd/system/gitblit_server.service and reloaded the daemon. How can I restore SELinux file?

Comment: You can do that by `restorecon -RFvv /etc/systemd/system`. Also make sure you have assigned the right permissions to the file `chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/gitblit_server.service`

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Plase update the question and include the contents of your file, permissions and the error you are getting exactly. See what `journalctl -xe` shows

Comment: All right...too dumb...the journalctl -xe lead the way...the /opt/giblit/gitblit.jar ... went into the next line and that causes the error. Thanks for your help. Provide it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong answer to create custom services. To start with, custom service files should not be placed within `/lib/systemd/system`  rather you'd use `/etc/systemd/system/your_custom_file.service`.

Secondly, after creating the service file you'd run `systemct daemon-reload` to notify systemd about your newly created file. Make sure you've restored SELinux file context using `restorecon -RFvv /etc/systemd/system`

After the update, the answer is obvious.

```
[Service]
.....
....
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -server -Xmx1024M -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar
   /opt/gitblit/gitblit.jar --baseFolder /opt/gitblit/data --dailyLogFile
....
```

Here, the line that starts with `/opt/gitblit/..` is treated as a single line and not part of `ExecStart` directive which is causing the error. You could simply fix it using a backslash as follows:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -server -Xmx1024M -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar \
   /opt/gitblit/gitblit.jar --baseFolder /opt/gitblit/data --dailyLogFile
```

Finally run:

`systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl enable gitblit_server.service`